# How to deal with Facebook thread IDs that contain forward slashes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When requesting a list of a users threads through https://graph.facebook.com/me/threads some of the threads are coming through with a forward slash character in the ID.

For example:

```
"id": "t_Cb0/atPMZaJw/cUuNtLW8B",
```

However trying to request this thread through https://graph.facebook.com/t_Cb0/atPMZaJw/cUuNtLW8B obviously fails due to the forward slashes

The error specifically returned is:

```
"message": "Unknown path components: /atPMZaJw/cUuNtLW8B"
```

I tried escaping the forward slashes with %2F but returns the same error, how can these be dealt with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are bug reports already about this, to
workaround: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=atPMZaJw%2FcUuNtLW8B should work (i.e pass the escaped string in the 'id' or 'ids' parameter instead of as part of the request path)